# Web Development: Cannot load an image

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, jsf-2

i'm starting to using the new version of Eclipse , version 3.7 (Eclipse Indigo).
My problem is simple, i'm developing in JSF 2.0 using GlassFish 3.0 as a server, if i try:

```
<img src="./images/services/1.jpg" alt="" /> <!-- it work -->
<img src="./images/about_us/1.jpg" alt="" /> <!-- it not work -->
```

Structure of the project:

[image: How the project is structured]

I really don't understand why this is happening folks.
Any idea ?

Best regards,
Valter Henrique.

Comment: @Andrew they're differents, is just the name that i put, just for convinience.

Comment: you're trying this from some of the .xhtml files, right? Why are you putting `./images/`? just `images`/ is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I was working with Netbeans before and now I'm starting to working with Eclipse (Indigo version).

My solution was refresh my project, I didn't know I have to do this, I used netbeans before, where is not necessary do this kind of operation.

Answer (score 1):

Well, did you try to respect the **case** of the filenames?

```
<img src="./images/about_us/1.jpg" alt="" /> <!-- does not work -->
<img src="./images/about_us/1.JPG" alt="" /> <!-- should work -->
```

So as said in comments, this was not the reason and this is in fact not the good answer. It was a refreshing problem.

Comment: i try, but keeps the same thing, it's like it cannot find the image.

Comment: ok, so try as well using very simple names (like 1.jpg) and check the read access rights and owner of the files & directories in the 2 directories

Comment: ooooh man, i'm so sorry for bothering you guys, my solution was refresh my project, i didn't know i have to do this, i used netbeans before , where is not necessary do this kind of operation, thank you all the answers.

Comment: @valter , you should then accept an answer or answer your own question saying how you solve it and accept your own answer. Please, read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and learn how to contribute to the community.